# Finding out local IP address using a UDP socket on a system with no Internet access

Tags: sockets, udp

I need to find out the local IP address on a very old platform which doesn't have `getifaddrs()`. Lots of people recommend to do this by creating a UDP socket, `connect()` it to a destination IP and then use `getsockname()` to find out the local IP address [(see here)](https://laforge.gnumonks.org/blog/20171020-local_ip_unbound_udp/)

Is there a way to make this work on systems that don't have Internet access? AFAIU, for UDP sockets `connect()` just sets the default destination address for the socket without actually establishing any connection. So can I just use some random destination IP with `connect()` because it doesn't connect immediately for UDP sockets anyway? I.e. can I just pass `8.8.8.8` as a dummy IP to `connect()` and `getsockname()` will still allow me to get the local IP address even if there is no Internet connection?

Comment: You can't query a socket for its local IP via `getsockname()` until the socket has been `bind()`'ed to a local network interface first. `connect()` performs an implicit `bind()` to a local network interface that has a network route to the specified destination, if the socket has not already been `bind()`'ed beforehand. So you can't just use an arbitrary destination IP, it needs to be at least somewhat legitimate since the OS will try to pick a suitable route to it, were you going to send packets to it afterwards (which you are not going to do in this case, but the OS doesn't know that).

Comment: What "old platform" are you targeting this code for exactly?  Just because it doesn't have `getifaddrs()` doesn't necessarily mean that it may not have other APIs available to enumerate local networks/IPs

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Target is AmigaOS. I've now implemented what I described in the OP and it actually works. I use `8.8.8.8` as the `connect()` sockaddr and then I can get the local IP from `getsockname()` just fine. It even works when there is no Internet connection. Can you elaborate on what you mean by the destination IP "needs to be at least somewhat legitimate"? Currently I have hard-coded 8.8.8.8 as the destination IP. Is that legitimate or what do you suggest to use instead?

Comment: by legitimate, I mean real, as in something you could actually reach out to if you tried. 8.8.8.8 is a legitimate IP - its Google's public DNS server.